# Spring Data JPA Projection nested list projection interface

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, jpa-2.0, jpa-2.1

I have a question about usage of nested list projection interface. I have two entity (Parent and child) (they have Unidirectional association)

Parent =>

```
@Table(name = "parent")
@Entity
public class ParentEntity {

    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    private String name;

    // other fields........
}
```

Child =>

```
@Table(name = "child")
@Entity
public class ChildEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @NonNull
    private String name;

    @NonNull
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private ParentEntity parent;

    // other fields........
}
```

I have two projection interface for select specific columns.

ParentProjection =>

```
public interface ParentProjection {

    String getName();

    Set<ChildProjection> getChild();
}
```

ChildProjection =>

```
public interface ChildProjection {

    String getId(); 

    String getName();         
}
```

I want to take list of ParentProjection which includes with list of ChildProjection.

Repository query like that =>

```
@Query("select p.name as name, c as child from ParentEntity p left join ChildEntity as c on p.id = c.parent.id")
List<ParentProjection> getParentProjectionList();
```

This query works, but it selects all columns of ChildEntity, and map only id, name propeties to ChildProjection. (generated query selects all columns, but i want to select only id and name columns)

How can i select only id and name columns (select specific columns for nested list projection interface) and map to ChildProjection fields (using with @Query) ?

**Note:** I don't need to use class type projection.

Comment: I don't think projections will work for an association that isn't present in the original entity. Either add the inverse side of the association or use a different mechanism for constructing the result

Answer (score -2):

You need to add the **OneToMany** relation to ParentEntity and annotate with **Lazy**.

Hope it helps *(i have tried this)*.